# Trying to compile to release mode for the first time and it bring up errors

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Can anyone tell me why when I try and build my solution in debug it works fine but then when I try to do it in release I get a wack of errors, especially with some referenced .dlls not being referenced anymore.

I have been working on this project for a while it is very big, and has alot of dependencies. I am now ready for it's first release copy and I cant get it going, I feel like I am missing something. Is there any flaws to distributing a debug copy of the software?

My next question is should I try and compile to any CPU or just compile to x86. I would like for everyone to be able to use the software? What is the norm?

Software is in vb.net using visual studio 2010.

Comment: "wack of errors" = ??? Why don't you post one or two of them with your question.

Comment: Also, take a look at the "Configuration Manager" under the "Build" menu. Are all your dependent projects marked to compile?

Comment: you do realize the error messages provide details into why the build failed. this information is required to resolve the build errors.

Comment: Voting to close due to no further forthcoming information. As it stands, solving this is guesswork. -1

Comment: All of the errors are releated to my dlls not being referenced causing alot of code to not work. I am asking if there is something that people have to do before being able to build in release because this seems odd to me. I was under the impression that it shouldnt matter what build I do it should still have my dlls referenced. I don't understand why you guys need to instantly downvote the post.

Comment: It is obvious I am not an expert on this matter. Every one of my issues has to do with referenced  objects not being referenced anymore when I try to compile to release.

Comment: I didn't "instantly downvote". I downvoted after leaving my initial questions standing for almost 30 minutes. That I returned to the question is actually an indication that I was trying to help, but you have wasted my time by not supplying more info. Other than compain about your treatment, you haven't added anything new to your question. How about adding more info to your question as requested, so the guesswork can be eliminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you post specific error messages its going to hard to give a solution, but it could well be simply a matter of copying the dlls from debug to the release folder.

Comment: Needing to manually copying from bin/debug to bin/release would simply be further indication that the project is incorrectly set up. Definitely **not** a good solution to the problems being seen.

Comment: Agreed, not a good solution at all, just a stab in the dark

Comment: Spender elaborate on how to "properly set it up". Is there something in the build settings I need to change for it to automatically add my references to the release folder? As it stands it is not copying them.

Comment: Well to start with, view references and check that the external dlls are set to copy local:true